# Mysql OR statement to return all row name values in array using AJAX then load multiple markers in Google Maps API V3

Tags: javascript, mysql, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, codeigniter-3

I have a doubt about my MySQL query, since when I search something like birthday, age, gender, etc., it cant return a result but when I search a name and last name, it returns only one result.

JavaScript/AJAX code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$("#searchDataToMarker").keyup(function () {
    var value = $(this).val();
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "<?php echo base_url('Maps/mapSearchDataInMarker') ?>",
        data: {
            'searchDataToMarker': value
        },
        dataType: "JSON",
        success: function (searchMapDataResult) {
            if (searchMapDataResult.length !== null || $('searchDataToMarker').value !== '' || searchMapDataResult['latlong'] !== '') {
                //we need to check if the value is the same
                $("#searchResult").html(searchMapDataResult['lname']);
                console.log(searchMapDataResult['lname']);
                console.log(searchMapDataResult['latlong']);
                var latlong = parseFloat(searchMapDataResult['latlong']);
                var myLatLong = new google.maps.LatLng(7.289600,125.678066);
                var iw = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
                var myOptions = {
                    zoom: 15,
                    center: myLatLong,
                    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.HYBRID
                },
                map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);

                var markerOptions = {
                    map: map,
                    position: myLatLong
                };
                marker = new google.maps.Marker(markerOptions);
                //for (var i = 0, length = searchMapDataResult.length; i < length; i++) {
                google.maps.event.addListener(marker, "click", function () {
                    iw.setContent(searchMapDataResult['lname']);
                    iw.open(map, marker);
                });
            //}
            } else {
                $("#searchResult").html('');
                alertify.alert('Search result empty.').set('modal', false);
                return;
            }
        }
    });
});
});
```

and my controller using codeigniter:

```
class Maps extends CI_Controller() {
public function __construct() {
parent::__construct();
$this->load->Model('Login_model');
$this->load->Model('Maps_model');
}

public function mapSearchDataInMarker() {
if (isset($_POST['searchDataToMarker'])) {
    $searchData = $_POST['searchDataToMarker'];
    $query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM resident WHERE name LIKE '%{$searchData}%' OR mname LIKE '%{$searchData}%' OR lname LIKE '%{$searchData}%' OR gender LIKE '%{$searchData}%' OR bday LIKE '%{$searchData}%' OR age LIKE '%{$searchData}%' OR citizenship LIKE '%{$searchData}%' OR occupation LIKE '%{$searchData}%' OR status LIKE '%{$searchData}%' OR purok LIKE '%{$searchData}%' OR resAddress LIKE '%{$searchData}%' OR perAddress LIKE '%{$searchData}%' OR email LIKE '%{$searchData}%' OR telNum LIKE '%{$searchData}%' OR cpNum LIKE '%{$searchData}%'");
    foreach ($query->result() as $searchResult) {
        echo json_encode($searchResult);
    }
} else {
    echo '';
}
}
}
```

My point: I just want to search anything inside my MySQL database and when the input match one of the contents inside the database(inside the column of name, middle name, last name, gender, age, birthday, etc.), it returns a array of result then pinpoint all the match result in Google Maps API V3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have three problems here: firstly, `mapSearchDataInMarker()` contains a SQL injection vulnerability, and you need to find out how to use CI to inject parameters safely.

Secondly, you can only return one JSON string, but you are echoing several.

Lastly, you are echoing an empty string in the case of no results, but this is not valid JSON.

```
$results = array();
if (isset($_POST['searchDataToMarker'])) {
    $searchData = $_POST['searchDataToMarker'];
    // @todo Fix security vulnerability
    $query = $this->db->query("
        SELECT * FROM resident
            WHERE name LIKE '%{$searchData}%'
            OR mname LIKE '%{$searchData}%'
            OR lname LIKE '%{$searchData}%'
            OR gender LIKE '%{$searchData}%'
            OR bday LIKE '%{$searchData}%'
            OR age LIKE '%{$searchData}%'
            OR citizenship LIKE '%{$searchData}%'
            OR occupation LIKE '%{$searchData}%'
            OR status LIKE '%{$searchData}%'
            OR purok LIKE '%{$searchData}%'
            OR resAddress LIKE '%{$searchData}%'
            OR perAddress LIKE '%{$searchData}%'
            OR email LIKE '%{$searchData}%'
            OR telNum LIKE '%{$searchData}%'
            OR cpNum LIKE '%{$searchData}%'
    ");
    foreach ($query->result() as $searchResult) {
        $results[] = $searchResult;
    }
}

echo json_encode($results);
```

I would guess you would now need to modify this JavaScript:

```
success: function (searchMapDataResult) {
```

to accept an array instead. Since you are using jQuery you can use its `each` iterator to process each item:

```
success: function (searchMapDataResults) {
    $.each(searchMapDataResults, function(searchMapDataResult) {
        // Original code here
    });
```

Note I've re-formatted the query too, for readability. I suggest you improve your indentation as well.

---

Edit: I have tried the live AJAX operation, directly by URL (Maps/mapSearchDataInMarker) and I get this:

> A PHP Error was encountered
>
> Severity: Notice
>
> Message: Undefined variable: results
>
> Filename: controllers/Maps.php
>
> Line Number: 482
>
> Backtrace:
>
> File: /home/ubuntu/workspace/application/controllers/Maps.php
>   Line: 482
>   Function: _error_handler
>
> File: /home/ubuntu/workspace/index.php
>   Line: 292
>   Function: require_once
>   null

Allow me to mention for the fifth time that if you check the raw response to this AJAX end-point, you will see this output. Since this is not valid JSON, there is no value in checking it in JavaScript. **Are you using the network monitor in your browser?**

From your code, it looks like this is the problem - your array variable initialisation is commented out.

```
//        $results = array();
```

Edit: I've also noticed that during a POST operation, the response does not have the right HTTP headers, and again, you are only returning a single record, as far as I can tell. To fix the header issue, after fixing the above variable problem, use this before the `echo`:

```
header('Content-Type: application/json');
```

Also, it looks like you need to debug the `value` passed to the AJAX op in the first place - it is always null in the live application.

Lots to debug!

Comment: yep, i knew already that there is something wrong with my MySQL query, i'll try the query and the jQuery code you've suggested. btw, i've getting used my indentation style, so tnx for the feedback, i guess it's not readable at all... ill beep back when this works.

Comment: i cant get the value of the column names. when i do `console.log(searchMapDataResults[searchMapDataResult])`, the result is `Object {resident_id: "14", name: "asdfasdf", mname: "adsfasd", lname: "adsfas", gender: "adsfasf"…}`. And when i do `console.log(searchMapDataResults)`, the result is `[Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object]` which makes me confuse on how to get thos values. Please help @halfer

Comment: @emo_noel10: did you try iterating over it with `$.each()`? Yes, if you do a `console.log()` on the results array you should get an array of objects - so you now need to iterate over them to read each one.

Comment: i tried but that's the result. question @halfer, should i store again this array: `Object {resident_id: "14", name: "asdfasdf", mname: "adsfasd", lname: "adsfas", gender: "adsfasf"…}` to get the results using this declaration of code to catch its result: `searchMapDataResults[searchMapDataResult]`?

Comment: I am not sure I understand your question, @emo_noel10. Your overall purpose is to return a set of results from your query to plot on the map, using JavaScript. So the first task, if you have made the changes in my answer, is to use your browser's Network Panel to see if the correct data is being rendered in the AJAX response. Do that next, please?

Comment: i tried it already and it gives the right results but i just want to know on how to get those results in a value form cuz when i perform this: `$.each(searchMapDataResults, function(searchMapDataResult) {
        
    });`, and when i `console.log()` the `searchMapDataResult` for ex: `console.log(searchMapDataResult)` the result is: `name, lname,lname...`.
i just get confuse on how to get those array values... how to do it with your suggested code?

Comment: @emo_noel10: you can access them using `searchMapDataResult.name`, etc.

Comment: i did this: `$.each(searchMapDataResults, function(searchMapDataResult) {console.log(searchMapDataResult.name)});`, the result is undefined. why?

Comment: @emo_noel10: I've no idea, I don't have your code in front of me. Can you prepare a JS Fiddle? What type is `searchMapDataResult`? Does the response in your browser Network Monitor look OK?

Comment: yep, but the result are undefined. i will prepare a js fiddle as soon as i can.

Comment: i dnt know how to apply my project file in js fiddle. maybe you can look my code in github under: https://github.com/emonoel10/System/blob/master/application/views/Backend/page_comp_maps.php, is that ok to you?

Comment: @emo_noel10: not really, I can't see the format of the returned JSON in a browser Network Monitor. Do you have a copy of the app live anywhere? (Neither is ideal, since on Stack Overflow we want questions that are clear from the question itself, i.e. without brittle supporting links, but I don't mind taking a quick look, as long as your feature does not need sign-up. If you do not have a live server currently, set up a free one at Cloud9 (c9.io)).

Comment: Have you checked the JSON/AJAX output yourself first? It will take you a few seconds, and I won't assist further until you can confirm you have checked it, and it contains the information you expect (i.e. several rows of data).

Comment: yeah, that's what im doing, to check those JSON/AJAX output, and what i said earlier, the result are still the same.

Comment: take a look at here: https://ide.c9.io/emonoel10/system, i clone my repo came from github.

Comment: @emo_noel10: I've tried running that, and I get `Unable to connect to your database server using the provided settings`. Please get it operational so I can see the output of the AJAX operation `:-)`.

Comment: The result is "still the same" as what? It does pay to be as clear as you can here `:-)`. I wonder if your AJAX output only contains one row, though if you can get things working, I will check it myself.

Comment: `$.each(searchMapDataResults, function(searchMapDataResult) {console.log(searchMapDataResult.name)});` result: undefined.

Comment: Ah yes, that is not what I meant. I want to know what the text output of the AJAX response contains. Does it look like JSON? Does it have a suitable `application/json` HTTP header? How many rows does it have? etc.

Comment: nothing @halfer, just undefined. but when i do `console.log(searchMapDataResults)` which is a object to get array results from .php, the results are: `[Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object]`.

Comment: You are still looking in the wrong place - you need to check the raw output of your AJAX. See my edit, and [follow this link](https://system-emonoel10-1.c9.io/Maps/mapSearchDataInMarker) to see the (broken) AJAX output. It looks like you expect this action to be rendered in a `post` operation though - if you want me to help you debug that, please tell me how to reproduce that post operation.

Comment: I spotted you gave access credentials in C9, so I tried the POST/AJAX operation. The parameter `searchDataToMarker` is always empty when typing a search string, and the response does not have the correct header either. I'll make another edit above.

Comment: how come? there's no errors in my network monitor. And even when i uncomment the initialized variable `$results = array()` and put the `header('Content-Type: application/json');` before the `echo json_encode($results);` in the controller, the results are still undefined. my purpose of declaring `$.each(searchMapDataResults, function(searchMapDataResult) {console.log(searchMapDataResult)});` is to check if `console.log(searchMapDataResult)` is throwing some results and check again if what it looks like(a form of pure JSON, or array, etc...).

Comment: And when i uncomment `$results = array()` and put `header('Content-Type: application/json);` before the `echo json_encode($results);` in the controller, the results in this: `$.each(searchMapDataResults, function(searchMapDataResult) {console.log(searchMapDataResult)});` is `0`,`1`,`2`,`3`,`4`,`5`,... 
when i input a complete name in the search field, the result stuck at `0`, i think when it get the equal string in the database, it will result `0`, but if  i currently input some string, it will result `0`,`1`,`2`,`3`,`4`,`5`,... where the results are like the inputted strings.

Comment: i do `$.each(searchMapDataResults, function (searchMapDataResult) {
                                                    console.log(searchMapDataResults[searchMapDataResult]['name']);
                                                });` and i get my desired output. thanks so much @halfer! check here: https://ide.c9.io/emonoel10/system to see what i am trying to get, just look at the firebug/console.

Comment: @emo_noel10, excellent! May I suggest you now accept this answer, to mark it as correct and resolved? To do so, click on the tick mark to the left. Thanks.

Comment: it didn't post multiple markers on the map when i search with like values in the input field.

Comment: Yes, I didn't even see a map, though that might be NoScript for me. Have you done some debugging? When I checked earlier it seems that the JSON response now contains several rows, so are you now iterating over them? Have you used `console.log()` to print data to the console? Your `var myLatLong` in the question is at a fixed position, if you have since updated this code, please update the question. (If you need to rewrite the question then please ask a new one instead, so that my answer above remains relevant).

Comment: @ halfer yes, i use `console.log()` to print data to the console. it seems quite alright in return values but in generating multiple markers is the new problem. Maybe i post new question since i change the js code based on my new idea.